# Odd behavior with step()

Tags: r

step() and stepAIC() produce a "remove missing values error" when running the code on data with missing values.

```
Error in step(mod1, direction = "backward") : 
  number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?
```

According to ?step:

```
    The model fitting must apply the models to the same dataset. This may be 
a problem if there are missing values and R's default of na.action = na.omit 
is used. We suggest you remove the missing values first.
```

I have a data frame with one variable which has four na values. However, when I run step on the lm object, I don't get the "missing values" error even though it has missing values. Can anyone tell me what could be going on?

```
    > d1$Impressions
     [1]        NA        NA        NA   6924180   9313226  27888455  
18213812  54557205  13495553
...
```

This does not produce an error message:

```
mod1 = lm(Leads ~ G + Con + GOO + DAY + Res + SD + ED + 
            ME + Impressions + Inc + Sea, data=d1)

step(mod1, direction="backward")
stepAIC(mod1)
```

Even with a variable which has missing values, it's not generating an error message. Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: The obvious question for you then, is, "did the stepping result in result in removal of the 4 variables for which that one row is 'NA'?" I can understand this, as the error comes in not if there are any `NA`, just if the number of rows in the model matrix changes whilst stepping.

Comment: Ah, since step is run on the model object, it looks like lm is disregarding the NA values. This is why I have: Residual standard error: 742.2 on 33 degrees of freedom  (3 observations deleted due to missingness) when I print the summary()

Comment: Think about it; you fit the full model, so you loose 3 observations due to `NA`s. R prunes the model back, but at each step it never gets to include those 3 observations because the variables with the `NA`s are still in the model. The elimination stops before it removes all 4 of the variables with `NA`s. Hence the number of rows never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason for the stated behaviour is this. `step()` fits the full model and hence drops 3 (as stated) observations due to presence of `NA`s. As long as the variables for which there are `NA`s remain in the model, the `lm()` function will remove those observations at each step. If stepping stops before it removes a variable that would result in one of the previously removed observations remaining *in* the model, then no error will be raised, because the numbers of rows in the model matrix will not have changed.

As an aside, stepwise selection like this is considered to be of somewhat dubious validity. Not least, in using it you a making a fairly bold statement that the effects of the eliminated variables are exactly equal to zero. This also has the effect of biasing the effect (estimated coefficients) of the variables retained in the model to have larger (absolute) value.

Alternatives to this stepwise selection include shrinkage methods such as the Lasso and the Elastic Net.